# How to create Jira ticket using powershell

Tags: powershell, jira

Here is the Script that I am using to create a Jira ticket, but it is not creating anything on Jira. It is running without any errors but not creating anything on Jira.
For **$apiurl** and **key** I have taken the url and key of my Jira instance but still cannot create any ticket on Jira.

```
$apiUrl = "https://your-jira-instance.com/rest/api/2/issue/"

# Set the required headers for the API request
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    "Authorization" = "key"
}

# Set the data for the ticket you want to create
$ticketData = @{
    "fields" = @{
        "project" = @{ "key" = "Service Desk" }
        "summary" = "Test"
        "description" = "Description of the ticket"
        "issuetype" = @{ "name" = "Service Request" }
    }
}

# Convert the ticket data to JSON
$json = $ticketData | ConvertTo-Json

# Send the API request to create the Jira ticket
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $headers -Body $json

# Print the response from the API
Write-Output $response
```

Comment: What is the response?

Comment: I am getting around 3 pages of response

Comment: And what does it say?